# unable to read hive table from spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am unable to read hive table that I have created using spark but I am able to see the databases.

```
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config("spark.master", "local")
    .appName("interfacing spark sql to hive metastore without configuration file")
    .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://3.96.56.4:9083") // replace with your hivemetastore service's thrift url
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "/apps/hive/warehouse")
    .enableHiveSupport() // don't forget to enable hive support
    .getOrCreate()
```

With the above code when I am able to check show databases I am getting result.

```
  spark.sql("show databases").show()

+---------+
|namespace|
+---------+
|  default|
|     test|
+---------+
```

but on using select query I am unable to get the table result and giving error:

> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to fetch table student_data. Invalid method name: 'get_table_req'

what am i missing to add in the connection?

Note: I am trying to connect to remote Hive server.

Update:
I have made some changes to versions Now I am getting a different error when trying to read a table:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException
```

Comment: The root cause is the incompatibility between spark and hive versions. Check the hive version and recompile spark with the corresponding version.

Comment: My hive version is Hive 1.1.0 and spark is 2.4

Comment: do i need to pass any additional parameters in the configs or this is suffice

Comment: how are you running the select query? can you try spark.sql(SHOW TABLES IN yourdbname;) and see if it shows the table in the output or not?

Comment: Hi Nikunj My issue has been resolved my issue was more from the server side permissions and socket issue